# Response.write javascript causing newline in Constant

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-2.0

I cant figure this out, here is my code:

```
Response.Write("<html><script type='text/javascript'></script></body></html>");
Response.End();
```

Which is causing this error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1010: Newline in constant

I'm not sure how to get around it. This is c# and asp.net 2.0.

Any ideas?

**It seems to be happening around the closing  tag - when I pull that out - it works fine. Hmm**

Answer (score 2):

Ok I fixed it, it was the closing  tag. Was causing an error.

Here is the fix:

```
    Response.Write("<script>\n");
    Response.Write("</script" + ">");
```

Answer (score 1):

The code shown is ok, show surrounding code. You simple forgot to close a string, or forgot to escape a literal quote, or a backslash, etc.

Answer (score 1):

"Newline in constant" probably means:

> You opened up a string `"` quote marker somewhere and forgots to close it.

The C# interpreter can gets confuse about which quote is actually opening and which is actually closing sometimes.

**Look at the last few lines you've edited and *check thoroughly* for any syntax errors.**

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but perhaps you copied the code from somewhere that had just a carriage return without a linefeed or vice versa? Try copying the code back from Stack Overflow into your editor.

Also, are you sure that the error is coming from *that* line of code?